# Using DateTime?.Value.TimeOfDay in LINQ Query

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, timespan

I'm trying to do a Query with LINQ on ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have a model, lets call it Event. This Event object has a Date property, of DateTime?. What I want is to fetch the Events that are between 2 TimeSpans.

Right now my code looks like the following:

```
TimeSpan From = new TimeSpan(8,0,0);
TimeSpan Until = new TimeSpan(22,0,0);

var events =
    from e in db.Events
    where e.Date.Value.TimeOfDay >= From,
          e.Date.Value.TimeOfDay <= Until
    select e;
```

An exception is thrown, telling me that "The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

I don't get a way around this problem, and I have been all day trying. Please help me, I'm so frustrated. :(

EDIT:

I Forgot to write here the "TimeOfDay" after e.Date.Value. Anyway, I did in my code.

I can't use DateTime because I have to filter Events that occur between certain time of the day, despite the date of the event.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't even use `TimeOfDay` - I assume in reality it does, instead of using `Date` (as per your code)?

Comment: Why are you using two TimeSpan objects instead of two DateTime objects to filter the events?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [Date and Time Canonical Functions for LINQ-to-Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(VS.100).aspx). Specifically, look at

```
CreateTime(hour, minute, second)
```

If you need help calling a canonical function, look at [How To: Call Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456873.aspx).

Comment: This seems to be on the track, I didn't know about Cannonical Functions. Thanks! But, how can I convert the DateTime to Time using these?

Comment: @Umagon: Use `datetime.Hour`, `datetime.Minute` and `datetime.Second`.

Comment: Oh my god! This solved my problem! I think I love you, LOL. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: @Umagon: I create feelings in others that they themselves don't understand.

Comment: So can I use this like context.MyTable.Where(entity => CreateTime(8, 0, 0) < CreateTime(entity.CreateTimestamp.Hour, entity.CreateTimestamp.Minute, entity.CreateTimestamp.Second) < CreateTime(16, 0, 0) to get entities which are created between 8 and 16 of each day?

Comment: Because I cannot use this with Ef core I decided to save TimeOfDay into database to ease my comparision.