# How do I compare only the time part?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm storing a time span in Sql Server as two columns of type datetime. (start and end)

So the date part of each column needs to be ignored.

Given some c# datetime instance, using an EF linq query, how can I determine whether the c# datetime's time is within the time span?

So the date part of all three values is ignored.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried?

Comment: This appears to work...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048527/how-do-i-compare-only-the-time-part/20048789?noredirect=1#20048789

Comment: Yes I posted a link to a similar question that's answer is what I was looking for so there's no need for us to carry on a discussion. Incidentally, I didn't directly reply to your comment.... I actually posted an answer but it was automatically converted to a comment. But thanks for trying to help me. If my responses are a little terse then I'm afraid I think I have been influenced by Stackoverflow's brutal etiquette.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry, sorry

Comment: ha, no need. I will be more polite in future.

Comment: I did misasses your attitude, please apologise my behaviour; I just want to contribute towards the elimination of disrespectful attitudes not appraising others effort (not here, in general). If everything was a misunderstanding and you act rightly, I do apologise.

Comment: Please, update this link as far as refers to this question (= is not what you want to do); just write your own answer or a new comment. In any case, you have got a pretty worthy answer; if this is not exactly what you meant, you should explain exactly what you meant; we cannot guess what you are after. Lastly, please, don't associate the behaviour of people like me with SO; SO does not have any responsability on what I say or do; not even about my interpretation of its rules. In any case and for the future bear in mind that it is usually better talking than not saying anything/interpreting.

Comment: Now you see we really do have a misunderstanding here because that link I posted was the wrong link. haha! It should have been this one... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10000571/221683

Comment: This is what I was saying. In any case, please note that in this link the OP posts his code and explains the problem clearly (from your description is impossible to know that you were referring to that) ... Also, as far as you are writing an answer, you should put something from your side: explain the exact problem and the exact solution (not just the link); otherwise, this whole question should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok I will mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract TimeOfDay property from DateTime that gives you the TimeSpan representing the time into the day:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.TimeOfDay;
```

Returns TimeSpan :

> 14:16:22.3100098

Comment: Nah, the Linq provider doesn't like it.